# Mostrar tabuada em uma tabela PHP

Tags: php, html, variáveis, tabela-html

Estou tentando colocar os dados de uma tabuada em uma tabela, no entanto minhas tentativas só criaram uma bola de neve que me confundiu mais ainda. Aqui está o código da tabuada que fiz até o momento:

```
<?php
    $tab=0;
      if(isset($_POST["tabuada"])){
        $tab=$_POST["tabuada"];
      if(!is_numeric($tab)){
        echo "<br>Digite um Número<br>";
      }else{
        $num=0;
        echo "Operação | Resultado <br>";
      while($num<=10){
        echo $num . " x " . $tab . " = " . ($num*$tab) . "<br>";
      $num++;}
      }}
  ?>
```

Minha ideia é que fique algo mais ou menos assim:[image: Tabela com 2 theads, onde de um lado ficam os operadores, ex: 3x1 e no segundo thead o resultado ex:3]

Agradeço desde já a atenção e a ajuda.

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você deve utilizar as tags html: table, th e tr.
Seu código deve ficar desta forma:

```
<?php
$tab = 0;

if (!isset($_POST["tabuada"])) {
    echo "<br>Digite um Número<br>";
    echo "<form method='POST'>";
    echo "<input type='number' name='tabuada' />";
    echo "</form>"; 
}

if (isset($_POST["tabuada"])) {
    $tab = $_POST["tabuada"];
    if (!is_numeric($tab)) {
        echo "<br>Digite um Número<br>";
    } else {
        $num = 0;
        echo "<table>";
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<th>Operação</th>";
        echo "<th>Resultado</th>";
        echo "</tr>";
        while ($num <= 10) {
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>" . $num . " x " . $tab . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . ($num * $tab) . "</td>";
            echo "</tr>";
            $num++;
        }
        echo "</table>";
    }
}
?>
```

Pra dar uma estilização básica, você pode usar:

```
<style>
table {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

td, th {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #dddddd;
}
</style>
```

Adicionei uma parte ao seu código pra que ele funcione 'standalone'.
Caso um número não seja informado, aparece um 'form' pra informar este número.

Comment: Muuuito obrigado, você realmente me salvou! :)